# Collect data from a form organized with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, flask

In this form you insert patient's data for a specific date. More fields can be added dynamically and if necessary, another table for another date entry, resulting in something like this (Here's the original entry and a dynamically one created):[image]

That being said, I need to retrieve the data organized like how is displayed on the webpage (For every new table, you get its date and the rest of the fields).
Is there a way to collect it using an iterable way (Like for each table inside this div ...)? That way I can categorize it the intended way.

So far I've managed to get them using request.form.getlist("name"), but it returns all the fields with that name together, being unable to identify to which date that value belongs.

HTML:

```
       <form action="{{ url_for('getdata')}}" method="post">
        <div id="evolutiondiv">
            <table id="evolutiontable">
            <tr><th><label>Fecha:</label></th><th><label>Tratamientos:</label></th><th><label>Analiticas:</label></th><th><label>Constantes:</label></th></tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><input type="date" name="treatmentdate" class="inputdata evolution" required></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="treatmentdiv1">
                        <div id ="treatments1">
                        <table  align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>ID:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="7" name="analyticid" class="inputdata evolution" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Valor:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="analyticresult" class="inputdata evolution" required></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" class="formbutton add" value="+" onclick="addtreatment(this)"/>
                        <input type="button" class="formbutton delete" value="-" onclick="deletetreatment(this)"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <div id="analyticsdiv1">
                        <div id ="analytics1">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>ID:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="7" name="analyticid" class="inputdata evolution" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label>Valor:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="analyticresult" class="inputdata evolution" required></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="formbutton add" value="+" onclick="addanalytic(this)"/>
                    <input type="button" class="formbutton delete" value="-" onclick="deleteanalytic(this)"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <table id="vitaltable" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="vitals" class="inputdata vitals" required></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="formbutton add" value="+" onclick="addevolution()"/>
        <input type="button" class="formbutton delete" value="-" onclick="deletevolution()"/>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="predictbutton" class="formbutton predict" value="Predecir"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function addtreatment(button){
         var div = document.getElementById(button.parentNode.id).children[0];
         console.log(div.id);
         var str = "<table align=\"center\">\n" +
             "                                <tr>\n" +
             "                                    <td><label>ID:</label></td>\n" +
             "                                    <td><input type=\"text\" minlength=\"7\" maxlength=\"7\" name=\"analyticid\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
             "                                </tr>\n" +
             "                                <tr>\n" +
             "                                    <td><label>Valor:</label></td>\n" +
             "                                    <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"analyticresult\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
             "                                </tr>\n" +
             "                            </table>"
         div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
    }
    
    function deletetreatment(button) {
        var div = document.getElementById(button.parentNode.id).children[0];
        console.log(div.id);
        div.removeChild(div.lastChild);

    }


    function addanalytic(button){
         var div = document.getElementById(button.parentNode.id).children[0];
         console.log(div.id);
         var str = "<table>\n" +
             "                                <tr>\n" +
             "                                    <td><label>ID:</label></td>\n" +
             "                                    <td><input type=\"text\" minlength=\"7\" maxlength=\"7\" name=\"analyticid\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
             "                                </tr>\n" +
             "                                <tr>\n" +
             "                                    <td><label>Valor:</label></td>\n" +
             "                                    <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"analyticresult\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
             "                                </tr>\n" +
             "                            </table>";
         div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
    }
    function deleteanalytic(button) {
        var div = document.getElementById(button.parentNode.id).children[0];
        console.log(div.id);
        div.removeChild(div.lastChild);
    }

    function addevolution(){
        evocounter++;
        var form = document.getElementById("evolutiondiv");
        var str="<table id=\"evolutiontable\">\n" +
            "                <tr><th><label>Fecha:</label></th><th><label>Tratamientos:</label></th><th><label>Analiticas:</label></th><th><label>Constantes:</label></th></tr>\n" +
            "                <tr align=\"center\">\n" +
            "                    <td><input type=\"date\" name=\"treatmentdate\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
            "                    <td>\n" +
            "                        <div id=\"treatmentdiv"+evocounter+"\">\n" +
            "                            <div id =\"treatments"+evocounter+"\">\n" +
            "                            <table  align=\"center\">\n" +
            "                                <tr>\n" +
            "                                    <td><label>ID:</label></td>\n" +
            "                                    <td><input type=\"text\" minlength=\"7\" maxlength=\"7\" name=\"analyticid\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                </tr>\n" +
            "                                <tr>\n" +
            "                                    <td><label>Valor:</label></td>\n" +
            "                                    <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"analyticresult\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                </tr>\n" +
            "                            </table>\n" +
            "                            </div>\n" +
            "                            <input type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton add\" value=\"+\" onclick=\"addtreatment(this)\"/>\n" +
            "                            <input type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton delete\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"deletetreatment(this)\"/>\n" +
            "                        </div>\n" +
            "                    </td>\n" +
            "                     <td>\n" +
            "                        <div id=\"analyticsdiv"+evocounter+"\">\n" +
            "                            <div id =\"analytics"+evocounter+"\">\n" +
            "                            <table>\n" +
            "                                <tr>\n" +
            "                                    <td><label>ID:</label></td>\n" +
            "                                    <td><input type=\"text\" minlength=\"7\" maxlength=\"7\" name=\"analyticid\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                </tr>\n" +
            "                                <tr>\n" +
            "                                    <td><label>Valor:</label></td>\n" +
            "                                    <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"analyticresult\" class=\"inputdata evolution\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                </tr>\n" +
            "                            </table>\n" +
            "                        </div>\n" +
            "                        <input type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton add\" value=\"+\" onclick=\"addanalytic(this)\"/>\n" +
            "                        <input type=\"button\" class=\"formbutton delete\" value=\"-\" onclick=\"deleteanalytic(this)\"/>\n" +
            "                        </div>\n" +
            "                    </td>\n" +
            "                     <td>\n" +
            "                        <table id=\"vitaltable\" align=\"center\">\n" +
            "                            <tr>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                            </tr>\n" +
            "                            <tr>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                            </tr>\n" +
            "                            <tr>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                                <td><input type=\"number\" step=\"any\" min=\"0\" name=\"vitals\" class=\"inputdata vitals\" required></td>\n" +
            "                            </tr>\n" +
            "                        </table>\n" +
            "                    </td>\n" +
            "                </tr>\n" +
            "            </table>";
         form.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );
    }

    function deletevolution() {
        if (evocounter > 1) {
            var form = document.getElementById("evolutiondiv");
            form.removeChild(form.lastChild);
            evocounter--;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? Have searched online and also read the documentation and still have no idea what else I can try.

Comment: You can enumerate the names, for example not `analyticresult`, but `0.analyticresult`, then `1.analyticresult` and so on.

Comment: And for the JavaScript, use multiline strings and template literals.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehn Numerating the names wouldn't help because there's no possible way to know how many entries and fields the user will add.